# How to get Gridview to pass a variable to code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am planning on using this function for the RowDataBound event of multiple Gridview controls. All gridview controls share one data source. Is it possible to pass a variable / command argument from the Gridview, so the function can filter the data according to the gridview that is getting data bound.

The data:

```
Subject_Id, AColumn, AnotherColumn
1, "something", "something"
2, "something", "something"
3, "something", "something"
3, "something", "something"
1, "something", "something"
1, "something", "something"
3, "something", "something"
1, "something", "something"
```

The function:

```
    protected void GridViewEng_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            e.Row.Visible = false;
            if (drv["Subject_Id"].ToString()=="1") // I want to pass the "1" from the ASP page.
            {
                e.Row.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Data Source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="repeaterdata" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ myString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT MyCols FROM ATable WHERE (Id = aVariable)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: surely better to filter the data source rather than the grid rows themselves?

Comment: But wouldn't I need multiple Data sources in that case?

Comment: Depends how your datasource is defined. You could fetch all the data from the database as one, but then filter it in code and send different parts to different gridviews. So the gridiews think they have different sources, but actually you only make one DB query. Difficult to be sure without more info about what you're trying to do, and how you fetch your data.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would do that? Also would that be a better way of doing things? Because it would involve more code. The Data source is defined in the ASP file and just fetches a number of rows that match my criteria, the data sorce has all the data I need for all my Gridviews

Comment: Well the process is exactly as I described, without knowing more detail of your data source I can't tell you exactly what to do. Or you could just make multiple database queries. Whichever way you go, if you want to display different data in each view, then you need a different source of that data.

Comment: I've added my DataSorce as an update

Answer (score 0):

I think I mind have found a way to do what I needed.

I will Name each Gridview something like Gridview(ThenMyID2)

```
String GVName = e.Row.Parent.Parent.ID;
String myidentifier = GVName.Substring(8);
```